# Invalid property 'semaphoreConfigs' of bean class [com.hazelcast.config.Config]:

Tags: java, spring, autowired, hazelcast

I am trying to start a hazelcast instance in my spring JUnit test. Below is the xml configuration i am trying to load as @ContextConfiguration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
<hz:config>
<hz:spring-aware />
<hz:group name="dev" password="password"/>
<hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="false">
    <hz:join>
        <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
        <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <hz:members>127.0.0.1</hz:members>
        </hz:tcp-ip>
    </hz:join>
</hz:network>
</hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

Am getting this below exception, any pointers is helpful

> org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'semaphoreConfigs' of bean class [com.hazelcast.config.Config]: Bean property 'semaphoreConfigs' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)

Comment: What Hazelcast version? What Spring version? Spring Boot or simple Spring framework?

Comment: This is Normal Spring Framework and Java Version is JDK 1.7. Hazelcast is 3.8 and Spring Version is 3.2.4.RELEASE. I am actually modifying an old project and try to write some test around to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception description indicates that Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE cannot process semaphore configs due to a discrepancy between getter return type and setter argument type. From `com.hazelcast.config.Config` class:

```
public Collection<SemaphoreConfig> getSemaphoreConfigs() {...}

public Config setSemaphoreConfigs(Map<String, SemaphoreConfig> semaphoreConfigs) {...}
```

`hazelcast-spring` is built & tested against [Spring framework 4.3.0.RELEASE](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/5a64facbfc7205f3fd05c39de173ac46b3fc1816/hazelcast-spring/pom.xml#L36-L36) and it handles semaphore config creation properly ([tested here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/bcf8bd402ddffeeb9823791b2416b557a4ad418c/hazelcast-spring/src/test/java/com/hazelcast/spring/TestFullApplicationContext.java#L484-L484)). If upgrading Spring framework version is an option, I would suggest doing so.